# Comparing Date with datetime format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, compare

How do I shorten the following statement:

```
select * from orders
where to_char(trunc(Cancel_Date,'MONTH'),'dd/mm/yyyy')='01/03/2015'
  and state = 'Cancelled'
  and to_date(to_char(trunc(Order_Date,'MONTH'),'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') < to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to retrieve orders that were *ordered* before March but *cancelled* in March? If so, I would avoid filters like this: `to_char(trunc(Cancel_Date,'MONTH'),'dd/mm/yyyy')='01/03/2015'`; if you have an index on `cancel_date`, then it won't be used (except on the off chance that you have a function-based index on that column!). I would do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
 WHERE status = 'Cancelled'
   AND cancel_date >= DATE'2015-03-01'
   AND cancel_date < DATE'2015-04-01'
   AND order_date < DATE'2015-03-01';
```

In the above query I am using ANSI date literals (supported in Oracle since 9i, I believe) rather than using `TO_CHAR()`, `TO_DATE()`, etc. And I am not applying any functions to `cancel_date` or `order_date` so that the optimizer can use the indexes on those columns (if they exist).

On a side note using `SELECT *` rather than explicitly naming the columns you need is generally not considered a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

in the second part of the where condition truncate isn't necessary:

```
select * 
from orders
where to_char(trunc(Cancel_Date,'MONTH'),'dd/mm/yyyy')='01/03/2015'
  and state = 'Cancelled'
  and Order_Date < to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 1):

The function trunc returns a date. You don't need to convert that to char and back to date again.

```
where trunc(Cancel_Date,'MONTH') = to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
and state = 'Cancelled'
and trunc(Order_Date,'MONTH') < to_date('01/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
```